# How to get the site address without subfolders?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I want to get the website url without subfolders, I mean everything replaced by `~`

For example:

> http://www.myWebApplication.com/a
>
> http://www.myWebApplication.com?somepage=b

I just want: `http://www.myWebApplication.com`

> http://www.myWebApplication:3345/c

I just want: `http://www.myWebApplication:3345`

Any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = new Uri("http://www.myWebApplication:3345/c");
var siteAddress = url.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + url.Host + 
    (url.IsDefaultPort? "":(":" + url.Port));
```

If it's the Request url, you can get it from `Request.Url` instead of building a new Uri.

Answer (score 1):

```
var uriBuilder = new System.UriBuilder
    {
        Host = HttpContext.Request.Url.Host, 
        Path = "/",
        Port = HttpContext.Request.Url.Port,
        Scheme = HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme
    };

var websiteUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host

Edit: You can play around HttpContext.Current.Request.Url to get most of the information you need from the URL

Comment: No, it gave me `localhost` only

Comment: What were you expecting to get? localhost:port?